# Which bar code type is the most robust when used with mobile machine vision and a tool like OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, barcode, qr-code, robotics

I want to use bar codes to help a robot navigate a home.  I was looking at QR codes and a few other kinds, but I don't know enough about bar code recognition to know up front the variant that will give me the highest success rate when viewed at different angles and perhaps even while the robot is in motion.  Does anyone know which bar code type excels in applications like this one?  I most likely will be using OpenCV in conjunction with one of the open source bar code libraries to do my work.  My users will print the bar codes on their printer an mount them on a stiff surface to create navigation placards placed at strategic locations around the house.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will go ahead and suggest [QR Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code)

Keep in mind there must be as little blur as possible and the image must be clear. I suggest you scale the QR Codes up so resolution doesn't become a problem(50cm x 50cm maybe?) and do not include a lot of data.

Answer (score 2):

zbar: http://zbar.sourceforge.net/download.html

zxing: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

I used zbar on ios for a very simple app, it worked pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the existing [ar_pose](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_pose) library (it's a ROS package) or the underlying library used by `ar_pose`, [ARToolKit](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/)?

Answer (score 2):

Both QR Code and Data Matrix are good choices. QRCode is more commonly used for end user applications, and Data Matrix is seen more often in robotic and industrial applications. If you needed maximum flexibility I'd recommend Data Matrix, and as of a few years ago it was still a marginally more robust code. But since QR Code is so popular these days and since there are so many implementations available, you might as well use QR Code.

Both QR Code and Data Matrix are robust codes. They can survive a certain amount of damage, and good decoders will work even if the code is viewed at an angle, in uneven lighting, or even if the code is located on a curved surface. One advantage of codes with built-in error correction is that they have only two read results: success that yields the correct data, or a decode failure and no data. You won't get misreads.

Open source implementations will probably work fine for high contrast codes (e.g. black ink on white paper), but if you end up having problems you might consider buying a cheap commercial smart camera from an industrial machine vision company. Some years ago I carved a Data Matrix into a hunk of light-color rubber with a pen knife, and with glancing light the code was readable to an industrial-quality decoder.